# Mapping app to plot several points

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, software-recommendation

I am looking for an iOS app that can plot several points (a.k.a. drop several pins) on the map at once. I would like to import the locations from a csv file or kml file and see all the locations at once.

Best: The app interprets the csv or kml and forwards me to the iOS native maps app with all the pins placed. This way I can use flyover mode and have a completely native map solution.

Next best: The app plots the points inside the app, but using Apple's API. (Flyover would be great, but I'm not sure that is possible.)

Acceptable, if I have to: Uses some kind of custom maps. I have found [Galileo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/galileo-offline-maps/id321745474?mt=8) and [arcGIS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arcgis/id379687930?mt=8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few applications for iOS that support GPX track information, which you could probably use to sort of meet your needs. I won't list them all, as there's quite a few (free and paid), with various focuses on walking/riding/hiking or photography (for geotagging images).

I've used [GeoTagr](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/geotagr-a.k.a.-geologtag/id294194869?mt=8) (formerly GeoLogTag) for quite a while for generating GPX files for geotagging photos. I believe you can copy GPX files in/out of it also, via iTunes (actually various methods to get the files out), but there are quite likely apps that make that process easier (try the ones designed for walking trails if you want easier import).

Again, **there's many more, with many different features, so just do a search for GPX on the iTunes App Store and see what suits your needs** (and let us know if any in particular suited your needs!).

Something like [Trails Lite GPS Tracker](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/trails-lite-gps-tracker/id306620245?mt=8) or [EasyTrails GPS Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/easytrails-gps-lite/id325929832?mt=8) might be more appropriate as they're designed to *import* GPX track files also, to let you follow the trail. I see no iOS6 Apple Maps flyover screenshots, but that's pretty new so I'm not sure if it'll just come natively since they use the native iOS Maps API, or if they'd need to be modified to support such things.

[Maps+](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/maps+/id416753449?mt=8) is another interesting one, which supports trails and bookmarking points (you'd probably need the paid version though). This one specifically uses the Google Maps data, apparently even with iOS 6. This includes elevation maps, which may be useful for tracks.

The caveat is most of these types of apps require you to use GPX files, which may or may not be a downside for you, depending on the current format of your data points. It's a reasonably common format though, and I'm pretty sure things like Google Earth can produce GPX files.

There's really quite a lot to choose from though, many with free "light" versions to test out...

Comment: Very helpful. Somehow I hadn't heard of GPX. There are so many junk map apps in the store, it is hard to find a good one, so thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [BatchGeo](http://www.batchgeo.com)? I just have, and I'm quite pleased with the results. $99/month for the pro version is a bit hefty (for me) but the free tools are more than adequate for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but things change rapidly on the App Store.

Full Disclosure: I may have had a hand in the development of the following app ;)

Have you tried [PointPlot](http://appstore.com/pointplot) on the App Store?

It should do what you are asking, and it exports in a number of formats. You can open files of the following formats: KML, GPX, GeoJSON and its own native format.

There is a free version called [iBuildMapAR](http://appstore.com/ibuildmapar) so you can try it out. Some of the features you get with PointPlot ($0.99) get unlocked with an in app purchase